# display static html asset in jekyll + github pages

Tags: github-pages

I want to add a link to a static html page (which I have created, not hosted anywhere). I added the html file to my images folder (contains the images which are being rendered in my jekyll blog). Then I make a hyperlink to the html files which I just added in the images folder, like this:

```
<a href=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/USERNAME/USERNAME.github.io/master/images/time.vs.score.html>View plots here</a>
```

Where username is my github username. This does not open a new html page, instead I just see the plain text of the html file. How can I add static html files are part of the assets? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thats what `raw.githubusercontent.com` is made returning raw file.Files are returned with `Content-Type:text/plain;` and then displayed as text by your browser.

You'd better link to github pages published content at `https://USERNAME.github.io/images/time.vs.score.html`

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy solution using this tool: https://rawgit.com/

just replace:

```
<a href=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/USERNAME/USERNAME.github.io/master/images/time.vs.score.html>View plots here</a>
```

with:

```
<a href=https://cdn.rawgit.com/USERNAME/USERNAME.github.io/master/images/time.vs.score.html>View plots here</a>
```